# Need to fill an array with const char* using std::string but it's not working(i think it's storing the pointers instead)?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a const char* defined in a class that i need to fill up with numeric data before storing it in an array

something like this

EDIT: Better minimum reproducible example code

```
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
    const char* a[3];
    std::string s1;
    void func1();
    void func2();
    void func3();
    //func4(), func5(), func6()............func50();
    void output();
    void print();
};

void A::func1()
{
    s1 = "1";//can be any number determined by the function being called
}

void A::func2()
{
    s1 = "2";
}

void A::func3()
{
    s1 = "3";
}

void A::output()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0:
            func1();
            break;
        case 1:
            func2();
            break;
        case 2:
            func3();
            break;
        }
    a[i] = s1.c_str();
    }
}

void A::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", a[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    A example;
    example.output();
    example.print();
}
```

I wanr the array here to be = {1, 2, 3} but instead it is {3, 3, 3}. There are several functions like this.

---

This is the prev one that's a bit complicated to explain so i've written it above

```
class A:
{

    public:
    const char* s1;
    void func1();
    void func2();
    void func3();
    //etc.. there are several 50 other functions like this but i've omitted them
    void output();

}

void A::func1()
{

    //do some function work here

    int data = 6//can be anything
    std::string n = std::to_string(n);
    s1 = n.c_str();

    //do something else
}

void A::func2()
{

    //do some function work here

    int data = 6//can be anything
    std::string n = std::to_string(n);
    s1 = n.c_str();

    //do something else
}

//etc...

void output()
{
    const char* a[16];
    int j = 0;
    while(something)
    {
    switch(i):
    {
      case 1:
        func1();
        break;
      case 2:
        func2();
        break;
      case 3:
        func3();
        break;
      //etc..
     }
     const char* a[j % 16] = s1;
     j++;
   }

    //draw a to the screen

}
```

Basically i need to store the "current" 16 int data's from the respective function called in the form of a string and draw it somewhere in real time(the array is pre filled with "NULL"s) but the **problem** is that the array gets filled with the same value. For example if func1() is 6 and func2() is is 5 and func3() is 4 and **currently func3() has been called** then the const char* a array is = {"4", "4", "4", "NULL"....} when it's supposed to be {"6", "5", "4", "NULL", "NULL"....}
so when i draw it to the screen in real time I see only 4's when it's supposed to be = 6, 5, 4, NULL, NULL, NUll.... I think the problem is that the array is storing pointers to the address string, so when it changes all the values in the array change. If any more clarity is needed i can explain

Comment: I've rewritten the code above to better explain what i mean

Comment: Well the same suggestion applies, why not make `a` an array of three strings? Pointers are hard and buggy, strings are easy.

Comment: @john: pointers are not buggy! The implementation of `std::string` contains a bunch of pointers. But they require very cautious programming and should only be used for low level implementations in modern C++.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Why is a[i] a char? Shouldn't it be const char*?

Comment: @JerSci! Oops I had not correctly read your code. But it is even worse because they are *dangling* pointers

Comment: @SergeBallesta Could you please explain why its worse?

Comment: @JerSci: I have explained it in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of *dangling pointers*! C++ is said to be immune to those (or at least less sensitive from C) but only if you do not mix raw pointers in the middle.

When you write `a[i] = s1.c_str();` you make `a[i]` point to the data owned by `s1`. The pointer is only valid until `s1` is modified. Here you are (un)lucky, because as all the 3 values for `s1` have same size, the implementation has re-used the same memory. So the 3 pointers still point to a valid address, that simply contains the last value of `s1`.

But formally, `a[0]` and `a[1]` are *dangling pointers* because they point to an object that has reached its end of life, and only `a[2]` is a valid pointer.